# 'no such file' error with Swift ArgumentParser package

Tags: swift-package-manager

I've added the Swift Argument Parser package to my Xcode Project, and I get the following errors:

```
dyld[12294]: Library not loaded: @rpath/ArgumentParser.framework/Versions/A/ArgumentParser
  
  Reason: tried: .... (code signature in PackageFrameworks/ArgumentParser.framework/Versions/A/ArgumentParser' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?))
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS@rpath/ArgumentParser.framework/Versions/A/ArgumentParser' (no such file)
'/Library/Frameworks/ArgumentParser.framework/Versions/A/ArgumentParser' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/ArgumentParser.framework/Versions/A/ArgumentParser' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

The build settings are defaults. If I select "Disable Library Validation", then it will run in Xcode, but the executable won't run in the Terminal, with the same errors.

My compiled executable will run without errors, if I copy the ArgumentParser Frameworks from the Build folder to `/Library/Frameworks`.

I'm on Ventura 13.1 and Xcode 14.1. Any idea how to get a single executable with all the dependencies built-in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the Package Manager adds the `generate-manual` tool to the list of Frameworks and Libraries in the project, but it's a CLI tool for building `man` pages, not a project dependency.

Deleting it from the **General** Options fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the SSH address `git@github.com:apple/swift-argument-parser.git` in the package search field in Xcode. I just tried it was and successfully added to my project. Adding the https address will result with error for this repo.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where that is? There are SO many settings! As far as I can tell, the package is added to the project, in spite of the error message.

Comment: select File > Swift Packages > Add Package Dependency and enter its repository URL. See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-package-dependencies-to-your-app

Comment: As usual, the documentation is out of date. There's nothing called "Swift Packages" in the File menu of Xcode 14. There's "Add Packages", which I have already done, obviously, and I can't change anything there, because it says I've already added the package.

Comment: If I paste the URL into the Add Packages dialog, I first get a warning that github is not authenticated, and then I have to create a token, and an SSH key, and all kinds of other password and security stuff that eventually fails.

Comment: The problem is not adding the package to the project -- it is added. It's just that Xcode initially doesn't validate it, and the executable doesn't embed it.

Comment: can you share the error log?

Comment: Where would the log be? I think we should get back to the original problem, rather than a possibly separate issue related to trying to add Github as a separate source for Packages.

Comment: Also, can you confirm that your method does create a command line executable that does not generate the errors mentioned in the question?